# why such a high memory usage?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a little program where you can click on a image and then it changes. But this little app has an extremely high memory usage and I can't figure out why :(. Or is it just normal and I have to implement some more methods for memory saving?...

When I click 12 times on my phone the memory usage is over 120 megabyte.
The images are all around 200kb.

Activity:

```
public class Activity_easy extends Activity {

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.easy_layout);

        Button btn_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        final ImageAdapter ImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(gridView.getContext(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ImageAdapter.switchImage(position, view);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] pictures;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        List<Integer> pictureList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            pictureList.add(i);
            pictureList.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(pictureList);
        pictures = (Integer[]) pictureList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return pictures.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

    public ImageView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;
        int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview);

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
        return imageView;
    }

   public void switchImage(int position, View view){

        ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
        int piece = pictures[position];
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            options.inSampleSize = 3;

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),mThumbIds[piece],options);
        img.setImageBitmap(icon);

    }

 // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1,
            R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3,
            R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5,
            R.drawable.pic_6,
        };
}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView

         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:orientation="vertical"      
         android:id="@+id/gridview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:numColumns="3"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
         android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"        
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/> 

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/back_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It could be that you are loading all the 12 images into memory and not disposing them off properly

Comment: you are creating 2 image adapters

Comment: This line is highly unusual : `final ImageAdapter ImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);`

Comment: deleted this line. same memory use as befor

Comment: Are actually running into `OutOfMemoryExceptions`? Is the memory usage continually growing the longer you actively use the app? Is your app becoming slow and unresponsive over time. Or is it becoming unstable and crashes at some point seemingly without any direct cause? If the answer to all those questions is no then you have nothing to worry about. High memory usage does not have to mean anything. You have not posted the specs of the device you are using, but if you have 1 or 2 GB RAM or even more then I would consider 120MB a completely normal memory usage.

Comment: I just looked at your code and I see **no indication** of any memory related problem at all. Though you might want to clean your code up a bit and follow the meaning convention a little more consistently ;)

Comment: And for the future: try to refrain from looking at the memory profiler unless there is some actual memory related problem. Memory management on modern systems is pretty complex and wierd and someone without the proper experience might interpret something as indication of a problem when in fact there is no such problem and what they are seeing in the memory profiler is completely normal behavior. Trust me, I believe every programmer goes through this phase at least once.

Comment: About 6 years ago when I discovered the memory profiler I also started looking for imaginary memory leaks even though there were none at all. Just save yourself the time unless there is any actual problem which requires looking at the memory profiler.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The problem is, that there is a OOME. And after every click, the next imageswitch is taking longer. On my virtual device I get the error after 6 clicks. On my S5 mini no error appears but it is getting slower and each click is adding more memory usage.

Comment: And I have alot of these messages in LogCat: I/Choreographer(1222): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This, like @Rakshith Ravi said, could be because you are loading image on top of image in your app. I am assuming you are setting onClickListeners for each image you post, right? This means whatever modifying you do to one image means you have to do the same thing to the others. Moreover, you have several of these images stacked one on top of the other. Since you are not deleting the previous image or accessing the images from a database, this will use a lot of your phone's memory. If you have any questions, please feel free to leave a comment.

Sincerely,

Ani

Comment: So how can I delete the previous images properbly? Most of the examples I used to build this code works like mine.

Comment: You can use the removeViewAt function. I will add another post to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a view, here is how to do it. I will crunch down your code significantly to show this.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id_here);

//I am assuming your imageview is the first item in the relative layout
layout.removeViewAt(0);
ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.whateverImage);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        layout.removeViewAt(0);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.whateverImage);
    }
});
```

Please edit this so that it fits your situation. Please let me know if you have further questions. I would be glad to help.

Sincerely,

Ani